# How to simply handle orientation changes?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm not talking about doing anything fancy. I'd just like the standard windows and views to rotate when the user rotates the device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tell the window which orientations it should support:

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    orientationModes: [
        Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT,
        Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT,
        Ti.UI.PORTRAIT,
        Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT
    ]
});

window.open();
```

You can then listen on the orientation changes with a listener like so:

```
Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e) {
    Titanium.API.info('Orientation changed');
});
```

Edit: I think (though I've never tried it) you can also set this in tiapp.xml, which has the added benefit of applying to all windows automatically.

```
<orientations device="iphone">
    <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
    <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
    <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
    <orientation>Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT</orientation>
</orientations>
```

Comment: I think you're right about the tiapp.xml config change. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
Titanium.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e) {
    Titanium.API.info('Gesture Change Detected');
    Ti.App.fireEvent('orientationchange', {eventObject:e});
});
```

Comment: So -- one must take the event, and then re-fire it, in order for the display to rotate?

Comment: this is an approach use to compartmentalize the functionality of a orientation change in each of my views. You do not have to re-fire the event

Answer (score 1):

this is work on android default. But not work on iphone, so just write this code

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
   title : 'Tab 1',
 orientationModes: [
        Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT,
        Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT,
        Ti.UI.PORTRAIT,
        Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT
    ],
});

win1.open();

Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e) {
    Titanium.API.info(Ti.Gesture.orientation);
});
```

I, THINK THIS IS USEFUL TO YOU.